# Can't get the scroll bar to display on overflow text

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I'm trying to lay out the main components of a site and have been mostly successful but when there's text overflow I seem to have done what resources say to put a scroll bar on an element.  Still, the scroll bar doesn't appear.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyle.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Random header text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
      Leftbar text.

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In numquam, fuga ipsam dolorum recusandae sed, quisquam accusamus provident autem repudiandae praesentium soluta ad. Beatae voluptatem voluptates dolorum id placeat laudantium.
    </div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="mainContent">
        Initial text.

        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta aliquid, nihil tempora, ex repellendus neque fugiat veniam voluptatibus quae vel dolores culpa, labore doloremque inventore vitae quam fuga velit esse!</div>
        <div>Molestiae saepe id asperiores harum porro iure dolores illo, ducimus itaque esse culpa repellat, deleniti, doloremque inventore fugiat, amet explicabo rem. In dolorum aliquid dolore consectetur modi, maxime voluptas nisi.</div>
        <div>Error veritatis dolorum numquam iure hic recusandae aspernatur ex incidunt corporis quam, praesentium modi consequatur maxime quidem minima asperiores voluptatem accusantium atque? Autem saepe non debitis voluptate maiores at, sequi?</div>
        <div>Facere repudiandae nemo quod perferendis obcaecati officiis quis rem consectetur eligendi at necessitatibus incidunt reiciendis ad cum accusantium doloremque praesentium dolorem nobis veniam explicabo cumque error iste laudantium, quo. Impedit.</div>
        <div>Esse earum voluptatum, libero tempore ad iure qui numquam iusto illo dignissimos quia quam laboriosam enim sapiente reprehenderit quod saepe provident consequatur molestiae ducimus, a accusamus dolores! Ea, officiis, esse!</div>
        <div>Fugiat reiciendis, recusandae quaerat deleniti rem fuga magnam ut earum aliquam esse veritatis at omnis culpa reprehenderit praesentium alias? Vitae inventore tenetur pariatur cupiditate, cum, ratione aspernatur suscipit reprehenderit nihil!</div>
        <div>Earum aliquid beatae qui! Facilis ipsum quos reprehenderit, architecto eveniet tempore ratione fuga voluptatum asperiores. Quia expedita quod vel totam velit dolorum placeat doloremque ab ipsa eius, dicta. Quam, eius!</div>
        <div>Tenetur impedit dolores consectetur deleniti doloribus, et ea quam cumque reiciendis fuga iusto vel, facere libero praesentium fugit alias sed ipsam dolor autem minus, saepe velit totam inventore? A, illo.</div>
        <div>Doloribus tempora non perspiciatis nobis pariatur quisquam deleniti, maxime voluptatem eum qui commodi, ducimus vel aut, unde corrupti libero, maiores sed perferendis nemo sequi? Repellat facilis rerum ut perferendis dolore.</div>
        <div>Blanditiis fugiat, veniam, repellendus quaerat ea voluptatibus, aspernatur voluptate ratione, in odit a. Aliquam quae modi debitis, voluptatum neque suscipit vel minus odio vero quibusdam earum nesciunt magni obcaecati fugit.</div>
        <div>Iure sed vel nostrum laudantium eligendi at quia, eaque numquam doloremque. Itaque cum reprehenderit quaerat nobis asperiores sed eum similique voluptatibus tempore necessitatibus porro doloremque, omnis molestiae cumque ipsam id.</div>
        <div>Omnis, dolorum, molestiae. Iusto quaerat nihil possimus soluta sapiente sit, doloribus eaque vero officia sunt hic nesciunt, omnis. Vel optio, illo eveniet inventore. Quisquam aliquid in quod, cum blanditiis libero.</div>
        <div>Veritatis architecto pariatur voluptatum ducimus molestias necessitatibus, delectus alias, mollitia ratione, fugiat perspiciatis accusantium rerum sapiente. Maxime nisi harum a recusandae vero ipsum ipsam repellendus, facilis quibusdam, tempore ratione ut.</div>
        <div>Enim voluptate nulla consequatur, tenetur quos quaerat suscipit distinctio ex in ipsam molestiae pariatur facere eligendi deleniti explicabo perspiciatis est placeat itaque libero repudiandae facilis. Labore voluptates distinctio reiciendis soluta.</div>
        <div>Repudiandae magni et inventore consequatur dolor enim eum officiis mollitia excepturi repellat vel, itaque eius tempora fugiat possimus, deserunt quam. Dolore nostrum accusantium eius quisquam perspiciatis facilis in ipsum, provident.</div>
        <div>Veritatis iste iusto molestias quisquam, veniam eveniet reprehenderit quos, in cupiditate eum rerum animi, assumenda, omnis natus voluptas a saepe. Et modi sapiente ipsum aliquid eaque unde, ea, explicabo impedit?</div>
        <div>Perferendis earum, dicta labore, nam nisi porro delectus non nihil iste excepturi cumque architecto voluptatum facere, molestias deserunt eaque magnam! A aliquam inventore molestiae? Voluptatem obcaecati voluptas, maiores veritatis voluptate!</div>
        <div>Perferendis eum natus praesentium neque provident rem repellat officia nobis, qui, eveniet reiciendis suscipit veritatis itaque mollitia ad asperiores distinctio necessitatibus magni excepturi dolorum officiis in sit corporis. In, quisquam.</div>
        <div>Incidunt fuga omnis commodi, facilis adipisci nulla hic. Delectus voluptas consequatur, iste dolor, quos quisquam quae totam provident, ipsam doloremque ea quas similique tenetur odit deleniti, voluptatibus maiores. Fugit, placeat?</div>
        <div>Dolores cum obcaecati, magnam vero rerum modi praesentium ad quo minus quaerat placeat, illo voluptas dignissimos quae, id harum velit sequi. Vitae, nobis voluptatibus non! Animi, consectetur, accusantium. Est, assumenda!</div>
        <div>Dicta, sint, nulla. Quos, tempore excepturi animi veritatis fugit perferendis eum repellendus commodi a aliquid enim qui doloribus consectetur vel provident rerum ipsum nisi iure adipisci! Dolorem praesentium eveniet voluptas!</div>
        <div>Hic beatae reprehenderit dolorum, impedit id rem mollitia, eos obcaecati amet nisi accusantium numquam, voluptatum aliquam, fuga iure rerum. Eos expedita delectus ipsum porro assumenda consequatur repellat a omnis architecto.</div>
        <div>Natus veritatis non dolorem vitae, maxime sunt, cupiditate totam quidem, illo sequi, odit eum asperiores? Libero mollitia ad labore maxime eaque, suscipit sapiente natus eum vitae dolore totam nostrum modi?</div>
        <div>Facere, voluptatibus reprehenderit voluptate nisi obcaecati magnam quod adipisci ea nam praesentium, ratione veniam rerum dignissimos id omnis suscipit commodi est, natus unde nesciunt tenetur et eveniet. Ducimus quidem, autem?</div>
        <div>Sit dolores debitis architecto recusandae dicta ea fugiat, eveniet non. Sapiente cum sunt quasi nihil, sint, ut, beatae saepe vel laboriosam adipisci sed iste temporibus! Porro temporibus error magnam aperiam!</div>
        <div>Sequi architecto placeat voluptate excepturi, similique labore illum accusamus perferendis, modi eius fugit aliquam, asperiores libero odio non! Ipsum perferendis, repellendus earum vitae architecto consectetur incidunt nobis possimus libero molestiae.</div>
        <div>Sapiente beatae officia, qui maiores eius libero suscipit! Voluptatibus tempora ipsam eum cumque iure magnam dicta amet doloremque. Ex similique officia repudiandae optio non illum perspiciatis fuga harum odit deleniti.</div>
        <div>Ducimus sequi esse, nostrum voluptate sit rem exercitationem cum expedita aliquid illum optio dolore cumque temporibus quis mollitia assumenda atque aliquam error deserunt, fugit ratione impedit, similique! Enim, praesentium, voluptate!</div>
        <div>Officia culpa, dolorem deleniti obcaecati ullam labore repudiandae eius sapiente totam necessitatibus pariatur expedita aliquid ratione corrupti, consectetur aspernatur adipisci eum dolores, facere. Facilis vel necessitatibus enim nihil eum architecto.</div>
        <div>Non aliquid quos, iusto culpa nam maiores molestiae, ratione laudantium adipisci, eum reprehenderit sed excepturi a debitis nihil possimus consequatur tempora, consequuntur incidunt rem! Molestias soluta id debitis ullam illo!</div>
        <div>Commodi sit, amet reprehenderit odit praesentium cumque inventore et, debitis repudiandae officia assumenda nisi ratione quos eos. Tempora necessitatibus maiores, dicta. In id hic laborum dolorum minima eius voluptatibus saepe.</div>
        <div>Quia eius nemo provident ut fuga expedita blanditiis eligendi accusamus fugit nihil quas excepturi officiis eaque modi possimus, unde adipisci soluta. Tenetur facilis, vero! A ipsa debitis veritatis voluptatibus soluta.</div>
        <div>Culpa iste ipsa aut nesciunt sit saepe sunt amet illum nobis repellat delectus, similique tenetur veritatis suscipit voluptate eaque repudiandae voluptates. Voluptate adipisci magnam, accusamus doloribus quos eius, nostrum dolor.</div>
        <div>Vel nemo voluptas rerum quis alias libero obcaecati quidem, aut similique ab explicabo quia, dolorum aperiam magni dolore temporibus voluptatum pariatur dicta iste! Ut debitis, voluptatum vero possimus ad culpa!</div>
        <div>Laboriosam unde illo voluptates reiciendis est ratione ab deserunt quibusdam, sunt omnis eos exercitationem recusandae inventore consequatur quas atque consequuntur nihil eligendi laborum praesentium. Exercitationem, repellat, autem. Quia, unde, totam.</div>
        <div>Delectus laboriosam suscipit iusto magnam veniam voluptatibus obcaecati, esse omnis nesciunt sequi. Quibusdam rerum error accusamus ducimus nemo excepturi eum quae, sequi, sapiente voluptate modi. Ratione quo ea enim quisquam.</div>
        <div>Architecto laboriosam perferendis ipsam molestias quaerat numquam eos minima reiciendis eveniet odit praesentium dolorem esse qui vitae harum a, quidem nisi quae, accusamus explicabo quod eligendi ducimus dolores blanditiis error!</div>
        <div>Minus nostrum, temporibus ab magni sapiente officiis enim pariatur error itaque saepe quos veniam amet dolor ipsum veritatis eaque dolore non officia cupiditate debitis recusandae blanditiis obcaecati. Aliquam animi, eligendi.</div>
        <div>Rem iste, nostrum, atque magni aperiam quia modi quidem qui officiis, quas soluta recusandae cum reprehenderit culpa perspiciatis ipsa dolore. Ab blanditiis saepe dolores ut voluptatem quas minus possimus, nihil.</div>
        <div>Cupiditate assumenda, quo doloremque earum voluptatibus voluptates consectetur magni itaque eius ea! Repudiandae, obcaecati, iure. Velit minus harum quam inventore, nihil rerum voluptas veniam obcaecati, totam doloremque beatae dolorum sapiente.</div>
        <div>Quisquam qui eos sit accusamus esse inventore consequatur iusto tenetur veniam, minima quae pariatur magnam ab non ipsa aspernatur rem quos, doloribus corporis. Repellendus molestiae, ab minus quaerat, totam reprehenderit.</div>
        <div>Neque dolorem necessitatibus cumque perferendis mollitia deleniti, voluptates, hic placeat quam, nesciunt quibusdam accusamus. Sunt, tempora, nobis. Repudiandae modi facilis sequi dolorum, deserunt labore, cupiditate illo hic consequatur temporibus impedit.</div>
        <div>Delectus odit magnam officia error placeat voluptatum, quidem quae consequuntur ipsam dolorem dicta nostrum, eaque qui quia amet maxime. Quae consectetur ducimus excepturi distinctio vitae. Quia, facilis obcaecati minima neque?</div>
        <div>Dignissimos pariatur veniam molestiae consectetur atque, ipsum voluptas quaerat nesciunt omnis fugit est fuga voluptatibus reiciendis soluta incidunt autem aliquam molestias quidem tempore nam maxime, eaque in accusamus inventore sapiente.</div>
        <div>Veritatis nostrum qui recusandae, dignissimos vero. Quam, at, nesciunt? Quaerat commodi, minus quidem sed. Quod dolor, temporibus nesciunt aliquam itaque, odio reprehenderit cum nisi blanditiis, quis ducimus, iste aperiam tenetur?</div>
        <div>Eligendi possimus vel similique praesentium est hic nemo blanditiis voluptatibus deleniti sit dicta accusantium quod facere dolor, ea, ipsam, odit a ex debitis quos reprehenderit. Iure veniam a laudantium praesentium!</div>
        <div>Voluptas maiores dolorum esse delectus, ratione nam cum eos! Minus reiciendis voluptates quo dolores laudantium, ea iure reprehenderit, delectus ipsa deserunt dolore voluptatem, quasi quod tenetur dignissimos ab eligendi! Vero.</div>
        <div>Amet, distinctio. Maxime culpa totam nesciunt harum alias eaque voluptatibus, aut explicabo recusandae reprehenderit. In, recusandae quia repellendus itaque doloribus maiores tempore corporis! Quos nemo itaque ullam, suscipit in unde.</div>
        <div>Illo at debitis ipsa consectetur, laudantium harum neque fugiat, eum ducimus sunt odio aliquid cupiditate atque deleniti assumenda facilis. Atque facilis esse nisi, mollitia animi maiores deleniti voluptates optio, doloribus!</div>
        <div>Velit quae, consequatur ratione laboriosam expedita sequi est illo sit. At fuga fugit tempora reiciendis omnis laboriosam nostrum aliquid rem architecto veniam cumque, maxime eveniet deleniti temporibus alias. Odit, dolor.</div>
        <div>Harum magnam, sint, possimus asperiores cum voluptate, ut ipsum, laudantium a dolore libero aperiam labore. Iure soluta voluptates placeat exercitationem omnis, quibusdam, alias quo iusto nihil tempore fugit iste ipsum.</div>
        <div>Ea, excepturi cumque ducimus accusantium facere itaque recusandae ipsam, nulla neque quibusdam quae vero quos vitae? A dignissimos, suscipit consequuntur cum odit vel nulla voluptates consectetur minus accusantium dicta veniam?</div>
        <div>Dolores iusto, enim voluptatem dolorum rerum neque explicabo libero aliquam nam odio tempore, sint quas aliquid. Praesentium vero at accusamus esse expedita mollitia ipsum nemo! Explicabo numquam ratione adipisci fuga?</div>
        <div>Quasi nesciunt, nobis. Provident quod illo asperiores cumque, aliquid quos repellendus est. Quo ratione, nulla doloremque officiis delectus quod, itaque voluptatum voluptatem nihil in harum quidem facilis ipsa est non.</div>
        <div>Mollitia quos nulla consequuntur, corporis doloribus, omnis enim nihil inventore, sunt qui libero labore quisquam iusto accusamus. Nesciunt esse expedita veniam, sequi facilis eaque vero. Temporibus nulla numquam dolores nostrum!</div>
        <div>Sed at amet doloribus porro maxime expedita illum quia non molestias, quas consectetur delectus rerum iusto atque voluptates laborum sunt dolorem dicta in! Fugit incidunt vero modi non. Amet, nihil.</div>
        <div>Necessitatibus, aliquid ullam. Blanditiis repudiandae, tempora et eaque iste aut, quo voluptate doloremque consectetur ullam nobis animi quisquam ad placeat illum reiciendis nam, corporis porro dolor nemo atque recusandae officia.</div>
        <div>Iste possimus nemo illum quia perspiciatis commodi autem dicta praesentium repellendus, laborum obcaecati voluptatibus unde alias tenetur labore voluptates, harum, deleniti dolore! Laboriosam sit, minus iure similique praesentium itaque inventore.</div>
        <div>Incidunt vero enim ratione, necessitatibus dolores perferendis aspernatur reiciendis sed, porro nobis voluptates, eum veritatis laborum hic at officiis iure nostrum. Est doloribus quidem quas commodi officiis labore eum vero.</div>
        <div>Officia fugiat eum nisi doloribus voluptates laborum ullam ipsa saepe distinctio veritatis nobis cum voluptatibus, eos, accusamus accusantium, cupiditate earum quisquam porro voluptate reiciendis sint, sit! Hic aliquid, tempore vitae.</div>
        <div>Sint laboriosam reiciendis dicta cupiditate ducimus adipisci itaque mollitia optio. Recusandae, soluta! Dolorum ex at saepe expedita. Voluptate voluptates officiis aliquam aspernatur, quas quidem quasi quisquam, esse nihil sequi voluptatibus.</div>
        <div>Consequuntur in eos, repudiandae dicta pariatur excepturi at doloremque repellat, earum dolores! Perspiciatis autem sapiente quae nisi natus quia culpa quaerat alias cumque, tempore officiis quam distinctio hic nihil error?</div>
        <div>Optio asperiores beatae esse maxime, vero facere laboriosam neque accusantium itaque nostrum minima voluptatem cumque possimus nulla hic officia! Sequi in nam rem totam alias aspernatur quasi atque reprehenderit voluptas.</div>
        <div>Suscipit, fugit ratione, dolorem maiores, quia quos corporis harum, iste repudiandae nesciunt rem minima quam eligendi. Nostrum facere iusto aliquid deleniti ipsam aperiam nobis, a quis debitis pariatur nam similique.</div>
        <div>Commodi provident, illum qui. Inventore maxime ea hic eaque, consequuntur, tempore molestias exercitationem culpa commodi illum quod adipisci ullam cum fugit praesentium accusamus odit porro libero incidunt quasi rem! Vero.</div>
        <div>Minus ullam, hic quo, excepturi perspiciatis reprehenderit culpa omnis repudiandae impedit beatae fugiat facilis ea neque fuga aut adipisci consectetur minima tempore deserunt ipsam earum praesentium aperiam est quae! Nemo?</div>
        <div>Nemo commodi, laborum doloribus quae distinctio, quasi alias, ex enim saepe vitae illum? Reiciendis temporibus hic, distinctio, eius illo maxime veniam mollitia, consequatur, sunt maiores pariatur. Qui nostrum, eum voluptatem.</div>
        <div>Corporis, illum, iusto? Consequatur autem ab adipisci facilis, ipsa maiores deleniti aperiam, explicabo perspiciatis, recusandae iusto minus omnis consectetur non quas ipsum! Tempora ipsa, unde eveniet a doloribus blanditiis reiciendis?</div>
        <div>Facilis illum dolore officia aperiam cum quam aut sint quidem alias sequi quisquam voluptatibus, velit quos doloremque voluptas nulla nihil! Amet eum earum pariatur veniam. Quasi, facere, possimus. Itaque, perferendis?</div>
        <div>Tempore porro facilis incidunt voluptatem sunt, vitae fugiat eveniet id fugit deserunt. Velit eligendi nobis sequi aspernatur, consectetur, ipsum. Quibusdam mollitia voluptas aut expedita accusamus error quam illum, ipsum possimus.</div>
        <div>Magnam id laudantium blanditiis asperiores corrupti eaque, rerum voluptates aliquid voluptate laborum adipisci impedit a, quidem dolorum! Beatae, natus odit, optio quam molestias possimus voluptatibus quia, dolores vel minus dolorem!</div>
        <div>Dolore nulla reprehenderit repellat, delectus dolores natus impedit neque accusantium voluptatem ut ipsa nesciunt. Sed sint similique, pariatur modi cupiditate vero, dolor dicta nisi dolore, consectetur recusandae temporibus, rerum commodi.</div>
        <div>Vero vel aliquid culpa tempora tempore atque perspiciatis eum quos ea tenetur natus necessitatibus excepturi quia hic maiores autem, modi magni neque officia veritatis. Obcaecati eius, id sit necessitatibus fugiat!</div>
        <div>Quos iusto saepe qui atque cumque maiores quas itaque, voluptatem, quisquam similique expedita fuga dolores, eligendi officia soluta ipsum necessitatibus delectus quo excepturi perferendis! Ea necessitatibus eum, dolore nulla debitis!</div>
        <div>Repellendus eius necessitatibus provident sapiente quaerat amet enim aspernatur nulla earum, eos rerum eum corporis quisquam vero odio autem aperiam, dolor iusto maxime voluptates aut eligendi unde quod! Perspiciatis, dolorem.</div>
        <div>Alias autem quis odit rem, expedita dolor. Laudantium facere nisi error! Maxime aspernatur, minus earum, accusantium odit dignissimos cupiditate dolorem explicabo fuga, provident sapiente qui exercitationem minima, sed totam hic?</div>
        <div>Saepe tempora nesciunt nam, perferendis. Incidunt voluptatem pariatur neque numquam, nobis, distinctio accusantium recusandae, provident veritatis praesentium quibusdam maxime molestiae hic consequatur. Expedita sequi, quibusdam culpa laborum ex asperiores distinctio.</div>
        <div>Quam totam optio sunt quibusdam pariatur sint nihil neque, laboriosam. Rerum temporibus optio nostrum libero excepturi, totam aliquid iure unde, voluptatem iusto rem, explicabo nihil dignissimos. Pariatur itaque suscipit perspiciatis.</div>
        <div>Deleniti a esse ipsam quis voluptas enim facilis ipsum dolore asperiores laudantium accusamus molestias, quibusdam sunt nesciunt facere laborum rem est veritatis sint hic cum officia ipsa! Delectus, explicabo, dolorum?</div>
        <div>Corrupti blanditiis ullam tenetur culpa perspiciatis! Culpa architecto, dolorem nobis ut assumenda deserunt doloremque magni laudantium, illo velit pariatur explicabo vel repellendus commodi voluptates eum quae obcaecati at vero mollitia!</div>
        <div>Cumque cupiditate amet, tempore ab aut totam neque saepe, reiciendis iusto asperiores et quibusdam doloribus architecto, illum sint iste. Deleniti aperiam, alias doloremque aliquid temporibus tenetur, debitis culpa asperiores quod?</div>
        <div>Libero necessitatibus ipsa, atque velit facilis sapiente fugiat dolor consectetur placeat eos aliquam inventore culpa corporis, vero reprehenderit perferendis. Aliquam quibusdam repellat, in atque ut repellendus soluta maiores! Quod, totam.</div>
        <div>Vitae eius, ut. Quod nesciunt fugit dignissimos sapiente hic ipsum, quo sunt dolore placeat labore amet quae iste necessitatibus repudiandae! Vero incidunt hic adipisci alias ipsam odio error inventore deleniti.</div>
        <div>Nemo facere quae architecto quos sunt odio atque, beatae, officia alias perspiciatis in sed ea, sapiente soluta iusto exercitationem quisquam eum repudiandae. Sint laudantium sequi incidunt ex tempore, quis velit.</div>
        <div>Facilis quos non placeat tenetur. Dolore vero doloremque cum repellat expedita perspiciatis voluptate consectetur nisi sint libero, quasi facere, est sit laborum nihil soluta quae deserunt, maiores ipsam in. Optio.</div>
        <div>Quisquam at esse illum, neque. Quaerat, nostrum nam nisi deleniti, iure rem voluptas quam dolorem magnam temporibus fuga maxime corporis. Excepturi nemo pariatur ratione. Neque cum totam inventore odio tempore!</div>
        <div>Maiores debitis beatae praesentium, labore facere suscipit explicabo. Doloremque vel dolor, error rem quisquam at repellendus numquam, cum dolore eos recusandae fuga, eligendi minus quo placeat expedita! Aliquam, nulla nobis.</div>
        <div>Aliquid vero molestiae facere mollitia officia labore, culpa necessitatibus fugiat quae quasi ex eum, pariatur similique laboriosam, libero voluptatibus placeat? Quae impedit eum sapiente dolores tempore dolor dicta officiis saepe!</div>
        <div>Dolor inventore quam in soluta non nulla veniam, doloribus consequuntur, veritatis quisquam expedita, autem temporibus sint aspernatur similique assumenda alias nam obcaecati molestias quis possimus dolore laboriosam rerum ut. Nostrum!</div>
        <div>Nulla inventore nobis eius. Sit quidem nostrum repellendus qui voluptatibus, quasi odit doloribus vero perspiciatis explicabo, ut itaque quibusdam tempore iure neque architecto similique error inventore quis soluta nulla tenetur.</div>
        <div>Nihil est earum aspernatur iusto natus similique velit inventore quasi animi aperiam cum labore magnam ex aut doloribus, accusamus sint fugit laudantium, repudiandae. Quo possimus, voluptates aperiam illo ratione adipisci.</div>
        <div>Voluptas corrupti ducimus iure distinctio nulla rerum quia quisquam impedit fuga odit alias accusantium animi possimus harum id neque, ipsa autem. Ullam officiis qui mollitia unde labore sed, natus illum!</div>
        <div>Eos facere dolorum ab natus reiciendis, non architecto quas iusto earum quasi corrupti nesciunt dolore hic laudantium placeat aut magnam? Esse natus explicabo necessitatibus beatae neque sapiente vitae maxime eos.</div>
        <div>Voluptate, voluptatum! At, obcaecati blanditiis qui expedita. Dolorem commodi obcaecati porro dolorum ut animi necessitatibus debitis neque, ipsam iure eligendi. Dolore eligendi accusamus, recusandae quibusdam corrupti hic laudantium similique magnam.</div>
        <div>Quas amet veniam cupiditate inventore tempore aut at neque modi veritatis nemo, sunt hic impedit beatae facilis commodi repellendus ratione fugit consectetur nisi magnam necessitatibus. Recusandae, magni deserunt corporis aut.</div>
        <div>Fugit magnam odio officia tempora asperiores laudantium nam beatae, a iste corrupti recusandae, consectetur possimus at! Ipsa, saepe, numquam. Atque aspernatur ex reprehenderit eos quis nulla explicabo quae impedit odit?</div>
        <div>Dolores asperiores, recusandae minima nobis, animi molestiae. Iusto tempora unde saepe corporis tenetur harum numquam eum repellendus atque officia cumque ut eos, laborum at quasi iste, recusandae quaerat deserunt suscipit.</div>
        <div>Ducimus recusandae, dolores ipsam, quos rerum facere! Quae deserunt iste corporis earum harum at quis, nobis dolorem necessitatibus ad odio, ea doloribus doloremque aperiam blanditiis maxime porro, voluptatibus. Culpa, iusto.</div>
        <div>Corporis eos nam culpa minus dolor. Nihil, atque beatae cum quod fugit placeat porro, dolorem quos. Obcaecati quae blanditiis ratione sit reiciendis architecto iusto voluptatibus, tenetur porro nam! Quasi, id.</div>
        <div>Nihil at vitae sequi eum nesciunt rem praesentium incidunt aliquam omnis sint molestiae eius, eos quod iure fugit quis odio adipisci id mollitia laborum voluptatibus fuga quas expedita. Voluptatibus, omnis.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**mainStyle.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#leftbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainContent {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100%-30px);
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

One thing I tried playing with is to make the position of the mainContent relative, didn't change anything.

I tried making the position of mainContainer relative and this put a scroll bar on the element, but then when it scrolls up the main content covers the fixed position header.

I tried it with the mainContainer having width 100% but found a StackOverflow question which guided me to trying the calculation above.

I searched for other indications of what might be causing this but can't find any more leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact your container has `position:fixed` and `width:100%`.

Which gives it the same size of `<body>`, but it should really have the width of the left column deducted (and same goes for height - deduct the header):

```
#mainContainer {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#leftbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainContent {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyle.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Random header text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
      Leftbar text.

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In numquam, fuga ipsam dolorum recusandae sed, quisquam accusamus provident autem repudiandae praesentium soluta ad. Beatae voluptatem voluptates dolorum id placeat laudantium.
    </div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="mainContent">
        Initial text.

        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta aliquid, nihil tempora, ex repellendus neque fugiat veniam voluptatibus quae vel dolores culpa, labore doloremque inventore vitae quam fuga velit esse!</div>
        <div>Molestiae saepe id asperiores harum porro iure dolores illo, ducimus itaque esse culpa repellat, deleniti, doloremque inventore fugiat, amet explicabo rem. In dolorum aliquid dolore consectetur modi, maxime voluptas nisi.</div>
        <div>Error veritatis dolorum numquam iure hic recusandae aspernatur ex incidunt corporis quam, praesentium modi consequatur maxime quidem minima asperiores voluptatem accusantium atque? Autem saepe non debitis voluptate maiores at, sequi?</div>
        <div>Facere repudiandae nemo quod perferendis obcaecati officiis quis rem consectetur eligendi at necessitatibus incidunt reiciendis ad cum accusantium doloremque praesentium dolorem nobis veniam explicabo cumque error iste laudantium, quo. Impedit.</div>
        <div>Esse earum voluptatum, libero tempore ad iure qui numquam iusto illo dignissimos quia quam laboriosam enim sapiente reprehenderit quod saepe provident consequatur molestiae ducimus, a accusamus dolores! Ea, officiis, esse!</div>
        <div>Fugiat reiciendis, recusandae quaerat deleniti rem fuga magnam ut earum aliquam esse veritatis at omnis culpa reprehenderit praesentium alias? Vitae inventore tenetur pariatur cupiditate, cum, ratione aspernatur suscipit reprehenderit nihil!</div>
        <div>Earum aliquid beatae qui! Facilis ipsum quos reprehenderit, architecto eveniet tempore ratione fuga voluptatum asperiores. Quia expedita quod vel totam velit dolorum placeat doloremque ab ipsa eius, dicta. Quam, eius!</div>
        <div>Tenetur impedit dolores consectetur deleniti doloribus, et ea quam cumque reiciendis fuga iusto vel, facere libero praesentium fugit alias sed ipsam dolor autem minus, saepe velit totam inventore? A, illo.</div>
        <div>Doloribus tempora non perspiciatis nobis pariatur quisquam deleniti, maxime voluptatem eum qui commodi, ducimus vel aut, unde corrupti libero, maiores sed perferendis nemo sequi? Repellat facilis rerum ut perferendis dolore.</div>
        <div>Blanditiis fugiat, veniam, repellendus quaerat ea voluptatibus, aspernatur voluptate ratione, in odit a. Aliquam quae modi debitis, voluptatum neque suscipit vel minus odio vero quibusdam earum nesciunt magni obcaecati fugit.</div>
        <div>Iure sed vel nostrum laudantium eligendi at quia, eaque numquam doloremque. Itaque cum reprehenderit quaerat nobis asperiores sed eum similique voluptatibus tempore necessitatibus porro doloremque, omnis molestiae cumque ipsam id.</div>
        <div>Omnis, dolorum, molestiae. Iusto quaerat nihil possimus soluta sapiente sit, doloribus eaque vero officia sunt hic nesciunt, omnis. Vel optio, illo eveniet inventore. Quisquam aliquid in quod, cum blanditiis libero.</div>
        <div>Veritatis architecto pariatur voluptatum ducimus molestias necessitatibus, delectus alias, mollitia ratione, fugiat perspiciatis accusantium rerum sapiente. Maxime nisi harum a recusandae vero ipsum ipsam repellendus, facilis quibusdam, tempore ratione ut.</div>
        <div>Enim voluptate nulla consequatur, tenetur quos quaerat suscipit distinctio ex in ipsam molestiae pariatur facere eligendi deleniti explicabo perspiciatis est placeat itaque libero repudiandae facilis. Labore voluptates distinctio reiciendis soluta.</div>
        <div>Repudiandae magni et inventore consequatur dolor enim eum officiis mollitia excepturi repellat vel, itaque eius tempora fugiat possimus, deserunt quam. Dolore nostrum accusantium eius quisquam perspiciatis facilis in ipsum, provident.</div>
        <div>Veritatis iste iusto molestias quisquam, veniam eveniet reprehenderit quos, in cupiditate eum rerum animi, assumenda, omnis natus voluptas a saepe. Et modi sapiente ipsum aliquid eaque unde, ea, explicabo impedit?</div>
        <div>Perferendis earum, dicta labore, nam nisi porro delectus non nihil iste excepturi cumque architecto voluptatum facere, molestias deserunt eaque magnam! A aliquam inventore molestiae? Voluptatem obcaecati voluptas, maiores veritatis voluptate!</div>
        <div>Perferendis eum natus praesentium neque provident rem repellat officia nobis, qui, eveniet reiciendis suscipit veritatis itaque mollitia ad asperiores distinctio necessitatibus magni excepturi dolorum officiis in sit corporis. In, quisquam.</div>
        <div>Incidunt fuga omnis commodi, facilis adipisci nulla hic. Delectus voluptas consequatur, iste dolor, quos quisquam quae totam provident, ipsam doloremque ea quas similique tenetur odit deleniti, voluptatibus maiores. Fugit, placeat?</div>
        <div>Dolores cum obcaecati, magnam vero rerum modi praesentium ad quo minus quaerat placeat, illo voluptas dignissimos quae, id harum velit sequi. Vitae, nobis voluptatibus non! Animi, consectetur, accusantium. Est, assumenda!</div>
        <div>Dicta, sint, nulla. Quos, tempore excepturi animi veritatis fugit perferendis eum repellendus commodi a aliquid enim qui doloribus consectetur vel provident rerum ipsum nisi iure adipisci! Dolorem praesentium eveniet voluptas!</div>
        <div>Hic beatae reprehenderit dolorum, impedit id rem mollitia, eos obcaecati amet nisi accusantium numquam, voluptatum aliquam, fuga iure rerum. Eos expedita delectus ipsum porro assumenda consequatur repellat a omnis architecto.</div>
        <div>Natus veritatis non dolorem vitae, maxime sunt, cupiditate totam quidem, illo sequi, odit eum asperiores? Libero mollitia ad labore maxime eaque, suscipit sapiente natus eum vitae dolore totam nostrum modi?</div>
        <div>Facere, voluptatibus reprehenderit voluptate nisi obcaecati magnam quod adipisci ea nam praesentium, ratione veniam rerum dignissimos id omnis suscipit commodi est, natus unde nesciunt tenetur et eveniet. Ducimus quidem, autem?</div>
        <div>Sit dolores debitis architecto recusandae dicta ea fugiat, eveniet non. Sapiente cum sunt quasi nihil, sint, ut, beatae saepe vel laboriosam adipisci sed iste temporibus! Porro temporibus error magnam aperiam!</div>
        <div>Sequi architecto placeat voluptate excepturi, similique labore illum accusamus perferendis, modi eius fugit aliquam, asperiores libero odio non! Ipsum perferendis, repellendus earum vitae architecto consectetur incidunt nobis possimus libero molestiae.</div>
        <div>Sapiente beatae officia, qui maiores eius libero suscipit! Voluptatibus tempora ipsam eum cumque iure magnam dicta amet doloremque. Ex similique officia repudiandae optio non illum perspiciatis fuga harum odit deleniti.</div>
        <div>Ducimus sequi esse, nostrum voluptate sit rem exercitationem cum expedita aliquid illum optio dolore cumque temporibus quis mollitia assumenda atque aliquam error deserunt, fugit ratione impedit, similique! Enim, praesentium, voluptate!</div>
        <div>Officia culpa, dolorem deleniti obcaecati ullam labore repudiandae eius sapiente totam necessitatibus pariatur expedita aliquid ratione corrupti, consectetur aspernatur adipisci eum dolores, facere. Facilis vel necessitatibus enim nihil eum architecto.</div>
        <div>Non aliquid quos, iusto culpa nam maiores molestiae, ratione laudantium adipisci, eum reprehenderit sed excepturi a debitis nihil possimus consequatur tempora, consequuntur incidunt rem! Molestias soluta id debitis ullam illo!</div>
        <div>Commodi sit, amet reprehenderit odit praesentium cumque inventore et, debitis repudiandae officia assumenda nisi ratione quos eos. Tempora necessitatibus maiores, dicta. In id hic laborum dolorum minima eius voluptatibus saepe.</div>
        <div>Quia eius nemo provident ut fuga expedita blanditiis eligendi accusamus fugit nihil quas excepturi officiis eaque modi possimus, unde adipisci soluta. Tenetur facilis, vero! A ipsa debitis veritatis voluptatibus soluta.</div>
        <div>Culpa iste ipsa aut nesciunt sit saepe sunt amet illum nobis repellat delectus, similique tenetur veritatis suscipit voluptate eaque repudiandae voluptates. Voluptate adipisci magnam, accusamus doloribus quos eius, nostrum dolor.</div>
        <div>Vel nemo voluptas rerum quis alias libero obcaecati quidem, aut similique ab explicabo quia, dolorum aperiam magni dolore temporibus voluptatum pariatur dicta iste! Ut debitis, voluptatum vero possimus ad culpa!</div>
        <div>Laboriosam unde illo voluptates reiciendis est ratione ab deserunt quibusdam, sunt omnis eos exercitationem recusandae inventore consequatur quas atque consequuntur nihil eligendi laborum praesentium. Exercitationem, repellat, autem. Quia, unde, totam.</div>
        <div>Delectus laboriosam suscipit iusto magnam veniam voluptatibus obcaecati, esse omnis nesciunt sequi. Quibusdam rerum error accusamus ducimus nemo excepturi eum quae, sequi, sapiente voluptate modi. Ratione quo ea enim quisquam.</div>
        <div>Architecto laboriosam perferendis ipsam molestias quaerat numquam eos minima reiciendis eveniet odit praesentium dolorem esse qui vitae harum a, quidem nisi quae, accusamus explicabo quod eligendi ducimus dolores blanditiis error!</div>
        <div>Minus nostrum, temporibus ab magni sapiente officiis enim pariatur error itaque saepe quos veniam amet dolor ipsum veritatis eaque dolore non officia cupiditate debitis recusandae blanditiis obcaecati. Aliquam animi, eligendi.</div>
        <div>Rem iste, nostrum, atque magni aperiam quia modi quidem qui officiis, quas soluta recusandae cum reprehenderit culpa perspiciatis ipsa dolore. Ab blanditiis saepe dolores ut voluptatem quas minus possimus, nihil.</div>
        <div>Cupiditate assumenda, quo doloremque earum voluptatibus voluptates consectetur magni itaque eius ea! Repudiandae, obcaecati, iure. Velit minus harum quam inventore, nihil rerum voluptas veniam obcaecati, totam doloremque beatae dolorum sapiente.</div>
        <div>Quisquam qui eos sit accusamus esse inventore consequatur iusto tenetur veniam, minima quae pariatur magnam ab non ipsa aspernatur rem quos, doloribus corporis. Repellendus molestiae, ab minus quaerat, totam reprehenderit.</div>
        <div>Neque dolorem necessitatibus cumque perferendis mollitia deleniti, voluptates, hic placeat quam, nesciunt quibusdam accusamus. Sunt, tempora, nobis. Repudiandae modi facilis sequi dolorum, deserunt labore, cupiditate illo hic consequatur temporibus impedit.</div>
        <div>Delectus odit magnam officia error placeat voluptatum, quidem quae consequuntur ipsam dolorem dicta nostrum, eaque qui quia amet maxime. Quae consectetur ducimus excepturi distinctio vitae. Quia, facilis obcaecati minima neque?</div>
        <div>Dignissimos pariatur veniam molestiae consectetur atque, ipsum voluptas quaerat nesciunt omnis fugit est fuga voluptatibus reiciendis soluta incidunt autem aliquam molestias quidem tempore nam maxime, eaque in accusamus inventore sapiente.</div>
        <div>Veritatis nostrum qui recusandae, dignissimos vero. Quam, at, nesciunt? Quaerat commodi, minus quidem sed. Quod dolor, temporibus nesciunt aliquam itaque, odio reprehenderit cum nisi blanditiis, quis ducimus, iste aperiam tenetur?</div>
        <div>Eligendi possimus vel similique praesentium est hic nemo blanditiis voluptatibus deleniti sit dicta accusantium quod facere dolor, ea, ipsam, odit a ex debitis quos reprehenderit. Iure veniam a laudantium praesentium!</div>
        <div>Voluptas maiores dolorum esse delectus, ratione nam cum eos! Minus reiciendis voluptates quo dolores laudantium, ea iure reprehenderit, delectus ipsa deserunt dolore voluptatem, quasi quod tenetur dignissimos ab eligendi! Vero.</div>
        <div>Amet, distinctio. Maxime culpa totam nesciunt harum alias eaque voluptatibus, aut explicabo recusandae reprehenderit. In, recusandae quia repellendus itaque doloribus maiores tempore corporis! Quos nemo itaque ullam, suscipit in unde.</div>
        <div>Illo at debitis ipsa consectetur, laudantium harum neque fugiat, eum ducimus sunt odio aliquid cupiditate atque deleniti assumenda facilis. Atque facilis esse nisi, mollitia animi maiores deleniti voluptates optio, doloribus!</div>
        <div>Velit quae, consequatur ratione laboriosam expedita sequi est illo sit. At fuga fugit tempora reiciendis omnis laboriosam nostrum aliquid rem architecto veniam cumque, maxime eveniet deleniti temporibus alias. Odit, dolor.</div>
        <div>Harum magnam, sint, possimus asperiores cum voluptate, ut ipsum, laudantium a dolore libero aperiam labore. Iure soluta voluptates placeat exercitationem omnis, quibusdam, alias quo iusto nihil tempore fugit iste ipsum.</div>
        <div>Ea, excepturi cumque ducimus accusantium facere itaque recusandae ipsam, nulla neque quibusdam quae vero quos vitae? A dignissimos, suscipit consequuntur cum odit vel nulla voluptates consectetur minus accusantium dicta veniam?</div>
        <div>Dolores iusto, enim voluptatem dolorum rerum neque explicabo libero aliquam nam odio tempore, sint quas aliquid. Praesentium vero at accusamus esse expedita mollitia ipsum nemo! Explicabo numquam ratione adipisci fuga?</div>
        <div>Quasi nesciunt, nobis. Provident quod illo asperiores cumque, aliquid quos repellendus est. Quo ratione, nulla doloremque officiis delectus quod, itaque voluptatum voluptatem nihil in harum quidem facilis ipsa est non.</div>
        <div>Mollitia quos nulla consequuntur, corporis doloribus, omnis enim nihil inventore, sunt qui libero labore quisquam iusto accusamus. Nesciunt esse expedita veniam, sequi facilis eaque vero. Temporibus nulla numquam dolores nostrum!</div>
        <div>Sed at amet doloribus porro maxime expedita illum quia non molestias, quas consectetur delectus rerum iusto atque voluptates laborum sunt dolorem dicta in! Fugit incidunt vero modi non. Amet, nihil.</div>
        <div>Necessitatibus, aliquid ullam. Blanditiis repudiandae, tempora et eaque iste aut, quo voluptate doloremque consectetur ullam nobis animi quisquam ad placeat illum reiciendis nam, corporis porro dolor nemo atque recusandae officia.</div>
        <div>Iste possimus nemo illum quia perspiciatis commodi autem dicta praesentium repellendus, laborum obcaecati voluptatibus unde alias tenetur labore voluptates, harum, deleniti dolore! Laboriosam sit, minus iure similique praesentium itaque inventore.</div>
        <div>Incidunt vero enim ratione, necessitatibus dolores perferendis aspernatur reiciendis sed, porro nobis voluptates, eum veritatis laborum hic at officiis iure nostrum. Est doloribus quidem quas commodi officiis labore eum vero.</div>
        <div>Officia fugiat eum nisi doloribus voluptates laborum ullam ipsa saepe distinctio veritatis nobis cum voluptatibus, eos, accusamus accusantium, cupiditate earum quisquam porro voluptate reiciendis sint, sit! Hic aliquid, tempore vitae.</div>
        <div>Sint laboriosam reiciendis dicta cupiditate ducimus adipisci itaque mollitia optio. Recusandae, soluta! Dolorum ex at saepe expedita. Voluptate voluptates officiis aliquam aspernatur, quas quidem quasi quisquam, esse nihil sequi voluptatibus.</div>
        <div>Consequuntur in eos, repudiandae dicta pariatur excepturi at doloremque repellat, earum dolores! Perspiciatis autem sapiente quae nisi natus quia culpa quaerat alias cumque, tempore officiis quam distinctio hic nihil error?</div>
        <div>Optio asperiores beatae esse maxime, vero facere laboriosam neque accusantium itaque nostrum minima voluptatem cumque possimus nulla hic officia! Sequi in nam rem totam alias aspernatur quasi atque reprehenderit voluptas.</div>
        <div>Suscipit, fugit ratione, dolorem maiores, quia quos corporis harum, iste repudiandae nesciunt rem minima quam eligendi. Nostrum facere iusto aliquid deleniti ipsam aperiam nobis, a quis debitis pariatur nam similique.</div>
        <div>Commodi provident, illum qui. Inventore maxime ea hic eaque, consequuntur, tempore molestias exercitationem culpa commodi illum quod adipisci ullam cum fugit praesentium accusamus odit porro libero incidunt quasi rem! Vero.</div>
        <div>Minus ullam, hic quo, excepturi perspiciatis reprehenderit culpa omnis repudiandae impedit beatae fugiat facilis ea neque fuga aut adipisci consectetur minima tempore deserunt ipsam earum praesentium aperiam est quae! Nemo?</div>
        <div>Nemo commodi, laborum doloribus quae distinctio, quasi alias, ex enim saepe vitae illum? Reiciendis temporibus hic, distinctio, eius illo maxime veniam mollitia, consequatur, sunt maiores pariatur. Qui nostrum, eum voluptatem.</div>
        <div>Corporis, illum, iusto? Consequatur autem ab adipisci facilis, ipsa maiores deleniti aperiam, explicabo perspiciatis, recusandae iusto minus omnis consectetur non quas ipsum! Tempora ipsa, unde eveniet a doloribus blanditiis reiciendis?</div>
        <div>Facilis illum dolore officia aperiam cum quam aut sint quidem alias sequi quisquam voluptatibus, velit quos doloremque voluptas nulla nihil! Amet eum earum pariatur veniam. Quasi, facere, possimus. Itaque, perferendis?</div>
        <div>Tempore porro facilis incidunt voluptatem sunt, vitae fugiat eveniet id fugit deserunt. Velit eligendi nobis sequi aspernatur, consectetur, ipsum. Quibusdam mollitia voluptas aut expedita accusamus error quam illum, ipsum possimus.</div>
        <div>Magnam id laudantium blanditiis asperiores corrupti eaque, rerum voluptates aliquid voluptate laborum adipisci impedit a, quidem dolorum! Beatae, natus odit, optio quam molestias possimus voluptatibus quia, dolores vel minus dolorem!</div>
        <div>Dolore nulla reprehenderit repellat, delectus dolores natus impedit neque accusantium voluptatem ut ipsa nesciunt. Sed sint similique, pariatur modi cupiditate vero, dolor dicta nisi dolore, consectetur recusandae temporibus, rerum commodi.</div>
        <div>Vero vel aliquid culpa tempora tempore atque perspiciatis eum quos ea tenetur natus necessitatibus excepturi quia hic maiores autem, modi magni neque officia veritatis. Obcaecati eius, id sit necessitatibus fugiat!</div>
        <div>Quos iusto saepe qui atque cumque maiores quas itaque, voluptatem, quisquam similique expedita fuga dolores, eligendi officia soluta ipsum necessitatibus delectus quo excepturi perferendis! Ea necessitatibus eum, dolore nulla debitis!</div>
        <div>Repellendus eius necessitatibus provident sapiente quaerat amet enim aspernatur nulla earum, eos rerum eum corporis quisquam vero odio autem aperiam, dolor iusto maxime voluptates aut eligendi unde quod! Perspiciatis, dolorem.</div>
        <div>Alias autem quis odit rem, expedita dolor. Laudantium facere nisi error! Maxime aspernatur, minus earum, accusantium odit dignissimos cupiditate dolorem explicabo fuga, provident sapiente qui exercitationem minima, sed totam hic?</div>
        <div>Saepe tempora nesciunt nam, perferendis. Incidunt voluptatem pariatur neque numquam, nobis, distinctio accusantium recusandae, provident veritatis praesentium quibusdam maxime molestiae hic consequatur. Expedita sequi, quibusdam culpa laborum ex asperiores distinctio.</div>
        <div>Quam totam optio sunt quibusdam pariatur sint nihil neque, laboriosam. Rerum temporibus optio nostrum libero excepturi, totam aliquid iure unde, voluptatem iusto rem, explicabo nihil dignissimos. Pariatur itaque suscipit perspiciatis.</div>
        <div>Deleniti a esse ipsam quis voluptas enim facilis ipsum dolore asperiores laudantium accusamus molestias, quibusdam sunt nesciunt facere laborum rem est veritatis sint hic cum officia ipsa! Delectus, explicabo, dolorum?</div>
        <div>Corrupti blanditiis ullam tenetur culpa perspiciatis! Culpa architecto, dolorem nobis ut assumenda deserunt doloremque magni laudantium, illo velit pariatur explicabo vel repellendus commodi voluptates eum quae obcaecati at vero mollitia!</div>
        <div>Cumque cupiditate amet, tempore ab aut totam neque saepe, reiciendis iusto asperiores et quibusdam doloribus architecto, illum sint iste. Deleniti aperiam, alias doloremque aliquid temporibus tenetur, debitis culpa asperiores quod?</div>
        <div>Libero necessitatibus ipsa, atque velit facilis sapiente fugiat dolor consectetur placeat eos aliquam inventore culpa corporis, vero reprehenderit perferendis. Aliquam quibusdam repellat, in atque ut repellendus soluta maiores! Quod, totam.</div>
        <div>Vitae eius, ut. Quod nesciunt fugit dignissimos sapiente hic ipsum, quo sunt dolore placeat labore amet quae iste necessitatibus repudiandae! Vero incidunt hic adipisci alias ipsam odio error inventore deleniti.</div>
        <div>Nemo facere quae architecto quos sunt odio atque, beatae, officia alias perspiciatis in sed ea, sapiente soluta iusto exercitationem quisquam eum repudiandae. Sint laudantium sequi incidunt ex tempore, quis velit.</div>
        <div>Facilis quos non placeat tenetur. Dolore vero doloremque cum repellat expedita perspiciatis voluptate consectetur nisi sint libero, quasi facere, est sit laborum nihil soluta quae deserunt, maiores ipsam in. Optio.</div>
        <div>Quisquam at esse illum, neque. Quaerat, nostrum nam nisi deleniti, iure rem voluptas quam dolorem magnam temporibus fuga maxime corporis. Excepturi nemo pariatur ratione. Neque cum totam inventore odio tempore!</div>
        <div>Maiores debitis beatae praesentium, labore facere suscipit explicabo. Doloremque vel dolor, error rem quisquam at repellendus numquam, cum dolore eos recusandae fuga, eligendi minus quo placeat expedita! Aliquam, nulla nobis.</div>
        <div>Aliquid vero molestiae facere mollitia officia labore, culpa necessitatibus fugiat quae quasi ex eum, pariatur similique laboriosam, libero voluptatibus placeat? Quae impedit eum sapiente dolores tempore dolor dicta officiis saepe!</div>
        <div>Dolor inventore quam in soluta non nulla veniam, doloribus consequuntur, veritatis quisquam expedita, autem temporibus sint aspernatur similique assumenda alias nam obcaecati molestias quis possimus dolore laboriosam rerum ut. Nostrum!</div>
        <div>Nulla inventore nobis eius. Sit quidem nostrum repellendus qui voluptatibus, quasi odit doloribus vero perspiciatis explicabo, ut itaque quibusdam tempore iure neque architecto similique error inventore quis soluta nulla tenetur.</div>
        <div>Nihil est earum aspernatur iusto natus similique velit inventore quasi animi aperiam cum labore magnam ex aut doloribus, accusamus sint fugit laudantium, repudiandae. Quo possimus, voluptates aperiam illo ratione adipisci.</div>
        <div>Voluptas corrupti ducimus iure distinctio nulla rerum quia quisquam impedit fuga odit alias accusantium animi possimus harum id neque, ipsa autem. Ullam officiis qui mollitia unde labore sed, natus illum!</div>
        <div>Eos facere dolorum ab natus reiciendis, non architecto quas iusto earum quasi corrupti nesciunt dolore hic laudantium placeat aut magnam? Esse natus explicabo necessitatibus beatae neque sapiente vitae maxime eos.</div>
        <div>Voluptate, voluptatum! At, obcaecati blanditiis qui expedita. Dolorem commodi obcaecati porro dolorum ut animi necessitatibus debitis neque, ipsam iure eligendi. Dolore eligendi accusamus, recusandae quibusdam corrupti hic laudantium similique magnam.</div>
        <div>Quas amet veniam cupiditate inventore tempore aut at neque modi veritatis nemo, sunt hic impedit beatae facilis commodi repellendus ratione fugit consectetur nisi magnam necessitatibus. Recusandae, magni deserunt corporis aut.</div>
        <div>Fugit magnam odio officia tempora asperiores laudantium nam beatae, a iste corrupti recusandae, consectetur possimus at! Ipsa, saepe, numquam. Atque aspernatur ex reprehenderit eos quis nulla explicabo quae impedit odit?</div>
        <div>Dolores asperiores, recusandae minima nobis, animi molestiae. Iusto tempora unde saepe corporis tenetur harum numquam eum repellendus atque officia cumque ut eos, laborum at quasi iste, recusandae quaerat deserunt suscipit.</div>
        <div>Ducimus recusandae, dolores ipsam, quos rerum facere! Quae deserunt iste corporis earum harum at quis, nobis dolorem necessitatibus ad odio, ea doloribus doloremque aperiam blanditiis maxime porro, voluptatibus. Culpa, iusto.</div>
        <div>Corporis eos nam culpa minus dolor. Nihil, atque beatae cum quod fugit placeat porro, dolorem quos. Obcaecati quae blanditiis ratione sit reiciendis architecto iusto voluptatibus, tenetur porro nam! Quasi, id.</div>
        <div>Nihil at vitae sequi eum nesciunt rem praesentium incidunt aliquam omnis sint molestiae eius, eos quod iure fugit quis odio adipisci id mollitia laborum voluptatibus fuga quas expedita. Voluptatibus, omnis.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also note the correct syntax of [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Notes) requires whitespace around `+` and `-` operators 
(I've noticed a `calc(100-30px)` in your code, which won't work).

Answer (score 0):

The overflow is hiding it. The `#mainContainer` is "pushing" the `#mainContent` to the right.
You have to change the `#mainContainer` `width`.
If you set `width: 90%`, for example, you'll be able to see the scroll bar that has been hidden on the right.